# How to move to Python 3.5 from Python3.4 rapidly?

Tags: python

Python 3.5 have been released for a week and I want to move to this version from 3.4.

However, I found that new version of Python is installed separately not 'upgrade'.

Especially on Windows, the default installed path of Python 3.5 changed a lot.

So, what is the best way to move to a new version of Python? I really do not want to reinstall all the packages again on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Have a look at virtuanenv and conda.

Comment: @Alexander that would still require one to re-install all packages.

Comment: You could attempt to copy all the packages `lib/python3.4/site-packages/` to `lib/python3.5/site-packages/`. But you should remove all the `__pycache__` files, and if there are compiled `*.so` files, this won't work: those files will need to be recompiled against Python 3.5. It's best to re-install all packages.

Comment: Of course it would.  But it only takes two or three lines of code in the terminal to update.

Comment: @Evert I have tried things like this and lead to a lot of unforeseeable problems, broken packages which was installed with pip can be fixed by re-install but some other distributions such as `pyqt` or `numpy` is much more hard to fix.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using a package manager such as [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/install/quick.html), this would be the install procedure:

1) port the names of your existing packages to a file, e.g. `requirements.txt`:

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

2) Install a new environment with the target version of Python and the relevant packages.  I'll assume your new environment in named `py_3_5`:

```
$ conda conda create -n py3_5 python=3.5 --file requirements.txt
```

3) Enjoy your new environment:

```
$ source activate py3_5
```

Note that you may have conflicts with your packages in your new environment.  There may packages that have yet to be ported to Python 3.5.  For example, the requirements of an optional `Pandas` package called `bottleneck` are as follows:
`Bottleneck Python 2.7, 3.4; NumPy 1.9.1`

This is why python package mangers were created.  You can't just change your python version and expect all previous packages to be compatible.  You need to create environments consisting of your target python version and then install the desired packages compatible with this environment.

Comment: I have `Anaconda` installed on my machine but unfortunately it is not my major environment. I am using official Python, is there any simple ways to do things like conda does using the official Python?

Comment: You can use this suggestion with `pip` as well, but you'd have to put in the full path to pip: `python3.4 C:/full/path/to/pip freeze  > requirements.txt; python3.5 C:/full/path/to/pip install -r requirements.txt`.